# Can't get element javascript google apps script

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the link element in a feed, i can get the `description` and `title`, but cannot get the `link` element. It seems weird to me. Here is my code

```
var url = "http://healthyhow.net/feed";
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var shareDoc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);

var root = shareDoc.getElement(); // feed element

var entries = root.getElement("channel").getElements("item");
for (var i=0; i<1; i++) { //just pick the first entry
    var e = entries[i];
    var title = e.getElement("title").getText();
    var link = e.getElement("link").getText();
   var description = e.getElement("description").getText();
}
```

Could anyone point out what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_xml#parse) indicate you should use lenient parsing for HTML - it's unclear what this is doing underneath, but in your case maybe it's confusing an HTML `<link>` element with a generic XML element with that same tag name.  It appears to parse the link entries into something like this for your code (which you can see in `shareDoc.toXmlString()`):

```
<link/>http://healthyhow.net/l-arginine-natural-treatment-for-hypertension/
```

Since it's an empty tag, no text.

Change:

```
var shareDoc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), true);
```

to be:

```
var shareDoc = Xml.parse(response.getContentText(), false);
```

and you should be able to get the link text.